# React Draft Wysiwyg - Image Upload button not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On a React.js Application I try to make the https://codesandbox.io/s/react-draft-wysiwyg-editor-forked-zn3ozh?file=/index.js editor to upload an image and embend it into the editor's content

But the problem is the code doesn't work as you see in the image below

[image]

the result should be the image below:

[image]

So how I can do that?

Comment: In the sandbox, I see the 2nd image with the Add & Cancel buttons.

Comment: Any solution by now?